# Azure databricks repos: how to pull via API

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-repos

I am using repos for Azure DevOps to connect Azure databricks to my respositories in DevOps. I need to pull automatically from Azure DevOps pipelines. For that I tried using databricks API to pull, but referring to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/repos) there is no method for pulling.

Following the instruction and looking at swagger the only methods available are:
[image: repos API]
**Is there a way to pull via API or CLI or any other way programmatically? If yes, how?**

Comment: You can check out my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73732631/programmatic-checkout-of-databricks-repos-branch/76821583#76821583

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `PATCH` endpoint as described in [documentation](https://redocly.github.io/redoc/?url=https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/databricks/_static/api-refs/repos-2.0-azure.yaml#operation/update-repo). It will Updates the repo to the given branch (or tag) - if you already on the given branch, then it will pull the latest changes.  You can also use `databricks-cli` for that, like, it's shown in the [following demo](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml#L78).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test your solution. I have exactly another problem at this link that I cannot make API call via PATCH. I have explained the errors I am getting in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72256036/azure-databricks-api-cannot-add-repos-using-service-principal-and-api-calls
Can you kindly see this too?